# Trying to get the last part of a URL with Regex

Tags: c#, regex

This is what I have so far:

```
string s = @"http://www.s3.locabal.com/whatever/bucket/folder/guid";
string p = @".*//(.*)";
var m = Regex.Match(s, p);
```

However, this returns `"www.s3.locabal.com/whatever/bucket/folder/guid"`.

Comment: Are you just hoping to get `guid`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Although [Uri.Segments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.segments.aspx) is probably the best way to do it, here are some alternatives:

```
string s = "http://www.s3.locabal.com/whatever/bucket/folder/guid";

// Uri
new Uri(s).Segments.Last();

// string
s.Substring(s.LastIndexOf("/") + 1);

// RegExp
Regex.Match(s, ".*/([^/]+*)$").Groups[1];
```

Answer (score 17):

Use the `Uri` class to parse URLs:

```
new Uri(s).Segments.Last()
```

Comment: Shouldn’t it be [`Segments`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.segments.aspx), not `Components`?

Comment: Thanks @Slaks, should I be storing my image URLs as Uri's instead of strings?

Comment: Add `using System.Linq;` to have access to the `Last()` method

Answer (score 1):

You could use this expression:

```
"[^/]*$"
```

This will select the value without the preceding slash.

Answer (score 0):

You could change p to be this:

```
string p = @"/([^/]*)$";
```