# regex, find last part of a url

Tags: regex, preg-match

Let's take an url like

```
www.url.com/some_thing/random_numbers_letters_everything_possible/set_of_random_characters_everything_possible.randomextension
```

If I want to capture "set_of_random_characters_everything_possible.randomextension" will `[^/\n]+$`work? (solution taken from [Trying to get the last part of a URL with Regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13369961/trying-to-get-the-last-part-of-a-url-with-regex))

My question is: what does the "\n" part mean (it works even without it)? And, is it secure if the url has the most casual combination of characters apart "/"?

Comment: \n = new line on unix (\r\n on Windows)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, please note that `www.url.com/some_thing/random_numbers_letters_everything_possible/set_of_random_characters_everything_possible.randomextension` is not a URL without a scheme like `http://` in front of it.

Second, don't parse URLs yourself.  What language are you using?  You probably don't want to use a regex, but rather an existing module that has already been written, tested, and debugged.

If you're using PHP, you want the [`parse_url`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) function.

If you're using Perl, you want the [`URI`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/URI/) module.

Comment: you made me discover a new set of function I could really use, thanks.
I ended up using basename()

Comment: I'm glad you found it useful.  In general, if it's a problem that is common, such as "how do I get just part of a URL", your first thought should be "I bet there is already functionality that takes care of that for me."  The best code is code you don't have to write, test and debug yourself.

Comment: That's something I always assume but I never remember.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this explanation: http://regex101.com/r/jG2jN7

Basically what is going on here is "match any character besides slash and new line, infinite to 1 times". People insert `\r\n` into negated char classes because in some programs a negated character class will match anything besides what has been inserted into it. So `[^/]` would in that case match new lines.

For example, if there was a line break in your text, you would not get the data after the linebreak.

This is however not true in your case. You need to use the s-flag `(PCRE_DOTALL)` for this behavior.

TL;DR: You can leave it or remove it, it wont matter.

Ask away if anything is unclear or I've explained it a little sloppy.

Comment: @user1722791: Great! Please accept the answer if it was what you were after.